# How do I write a singleton class in mod_python which works across requests?

Tags: python, singleton, mod-python

I have been trying to implement a singleton class for mod_python. It works fine while working in a single request but instantiates a new object when I call from a new request(as expected). How can I have a class with a common object across requests. What will be its lifetime?

Comment: This just sounds like a bad idea to begin with.

Comment: May well be. I just want to try out couple of things

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know persistence in mod_python is handled through the [Session](http://www.modpython.org/live/current/doc-html/pyapi-sess.html)-module. So you are not really looking for a (probably bad) singleton-pattern but more likely for a way to achive persistence over a range of requests.